# Is it possible to have zero gravity points on earth by changing the angular speed of rotation of earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, rotation

Let **F(gravitation)** be force due to gravity , and **F(pseudo)** be the pseudo force in earth's frame of reference.

It comes to me that those two forces are not parallel (see the image) and will never cancel .

[image]

Comment: Sure, they could only cancel at the equator. But I'm not sure what your point is, since it's not like there's any practical way to speed up the Earth's rotation rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could speed up the rotation until the centripetal acceleration was equal to the gravitational force then yes, you would have a zero g effect.

As you say though the angular speed needed would depend on the latitude: the first to feel zero g would be the people at the Equator, where $F_{pseudo}$ if antiparallel to $F_{gravitational}$.

As for the different directions of the forces, only the radial direction of the pseudoforce can contrast the gravitational force: a person sitting on the exact north or south pole would feel normal gravity, no matter of the angular speed. The component tangential to the surface instead pushes you towards the Equator: if the surface of the Earth was frictionless we would gradually all align along the Equator.